# How to implement typeahead using ionic without bootstrap

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic and would like to implement a typeahead for displaying the users list without using Bootstrap and would love if provided with an example .

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for something similar for an ionic app I was building. I can provide a few links that you can look at and choose the most appropriate for your case.

https://github.com/sn0opr/ionic-autocomplete

https://github.com/guylabs/ion-autocomplete

http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-typeahead-widget-with-angularjs/

The last link is written is great tutorial written in pure angular. The first two links are projects you need to include in your app and then use them as directives to achieve your goal. Cheers!

Comment: Would love to hear which one you went with and why